# Accessing navigator.mediaDevices in insecure connection for MS Edge

Tags: javascript, getusermedia, mediadevices

I have tried (javascript) to use navigator.mediaDevices use insecure connection (http) in MS Edge (v.111), but this field was undefined.
How can I use it ? Which settings should I do in MS Edge to get access to mediaDevices ?

Answer (score 1):

`navigator.mediaDevices()` access is simply not available unless you use a secure connection. Because cybercreeps.

Comment: O. Jones, thank you for your reply!   In Firefox it still can be done. You said - in MS Edge is impossilbe ?

Comment: Edge and Chrome share the same Chromium code base, and it can't be done in Chromium. By design.